# VBA output ComboBox value into the next free cell in Column

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I'm attempting to output the value from a Userform text box into the next empty cell in a column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        Dim LastRow As Long
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
            With .Range("H" & LastRow)
                .Value2 = TextBox1.Value
            End With
        End With
End Sub
```

However, it won't work and I receive no error messages.

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *Changed to CommandButton2

```
     Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
     Dim LastRow As Long
     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
     LastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
     Range("H" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
     End With
     End Sub
```